# How To Show A 503 Error For a Single Page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to show a 503 error for a page on my website. (Using htacess) So far I've tried the following but it seems to be not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /league.php [R=503,L]
```

Is this correct? Or is there anyway to give the absolute URL path? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts in your question. Could you please do mention for which URL you need 503 return?  For better understanding of question.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. For an example, I want to show a 503 when a user visits my http://example.com/webmail URL.

Comment: sure, is it only url ending with `webmail` only or you have any logic to catch these urls(in case there are many of them), kindly do let know here.

Comment: It is just the http://example.com/webmail URL :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, tested and written with shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webmail/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ league.php [R=503,L]
```

OR using errordocument option.

```
ErrorDocument 503 /league.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webmail/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

Comment: You don't need to use an URI in the substitution string since the redirect is handled by `R=503` .  However,Your second solution is good 

Comment: It should look like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ -  [R=503,L]`

Comment: @AmitVerma, Hey Amit, I have changed my 1st solution also, please do let me know if this looks good now.